# confusion about char array and pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, character

Here is the code:

```
char a[][5] = { "abc", "ijk", "defg", "opq" };
char *p = &a[1][1];
printf("%d,%s,%s", a[2] - a[0], &p[1], &p[5]);
// the output is: 10 k "efg"
// what I think is: 3 k 'e'
```

As I belive, a[2] is 'd' and a[0] is 'a',so I get 3. However, a[2] and a[0] are string types, so how can they do the minus operation? Finally, why is &p[5] "efg"? I am confused about my results.

Comment: `a` is an array of character arrays. Why would `a[2]` be anything but `"defg"`?

Comment: Remember, in C an array is often just convenient semantics around what's actually a pointer.

Comment: I get it,a[2] is "defg" and a[0] is "abc",they are both array of character,but why the output of a[2] - a[0] is 10 ?

Comment: One question per Stackoverflow question, please. You're asking multiple questions about array arithmetic. Can you please focus on the most important one, first, [edit] and ask as single, specific, question?

Comment: Consider what `a[2] - a[0]` represents in terms of *pointers* and what *pointer math* means here. How big is each element in `a`, for example? What does the memory layout of `a` look like? What would happen if you defined it as `a[][10]`?

Comment: In `a[2] - a[0]`,  both `a[2]` and `a[0]` are of type `char [5]` (containing strings `"abc"` and `"defg"` respectively). Both are converted to `char *` before subtracting, so the expression subtracts the address of the `'a`' from the address of the `'d'`. Arrays are contiguous, so there are ten bytes (two arrays of five characters) between them, so the difference is `10`. Incidentally, subtracting pointers gives a result of type `std::ptrdiff_t`, which is not (necessarily) an `int`, so  using `%d` to print gives undefined behaviour - so your code produced the right result through luck only.

Comment: *"a[0] is string type"* -- be careful of the terminology. The only standard type that exclusively represents strings is `std::string`. You are dealing with string literals, and the type of string literals is not `std::string`. (Also the type of string literals is slightly different than the type of `a[0]`, as string literals have `const` characters.)

Comment: I understand.thanks for helping,I am much more clearly now.@Peter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, think about what `a` and `p` are.  Here's a visual representation of them:

```
a
┌────────────────────────────────┬─────────────────────────────────┬─────────────────────────────────┬────────────────────────────────┐
│┌─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┐ │ ┌─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┐ │ ┌─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┐ │ ┌─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┐│
││     │     │     │     │     │ │ │     │     │     │     │     │ │ │     │     │     │     │     │ │ │     │     │     │     │     ││
││ 'a' │ 'b' │ 'c' │ '\0'│     │ │ │ 'i' │ 'j' │ 'k' │ '\0'│     │ │ │ 'd' │ 'e' │ 'f' │ 'g' │ '\0'│ │ │ 'o' │ 'p' │ 'q' │ '\0'│     ││
││     │     │     │     │     │ │ │     │     │     │     │     │ │ │     │     │     │     │     │ │ │     │     │     │     │     ││
│└─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┘ │ └─────┴──▲──┴─────┴─────┴─────┘ │ └─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┘ │ └─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┘│
└────────────────────────────────┴──────────┼──────────────────────┴─────────────────────────────────┴────────────────────────────────┘
                                            │
p                                           │
┌────────────┐                              │
│            │                              │
│      ──────┼──────────────────────────────┘
│            │
└────────────┘
```

`a` is an array of 4 arrays of 5 `char`s and `p` is a pointer to the 2nd element of the 2nd array in `a`.

From that, you can figure out what all of your parameters to `printf` mean:

- `a[2] - a[0]`:  Since `a` is an array of arrays, `a[2]` and `a[0]` must be arrays.  Now, you can't subtract arrays, but arrays in C++ are implicitly convertible to a pointer to their first element.  That means that `a[2] - a[0]` means "the difference between a pointer to the first element of the 3rd array in `a` and a pointer to the first element of the first array in `a`"  As you can see in the diagram above, there are 10 spaces for `char`s between those two elements, so you get 10.
- `&p[1]`: As you can see from the diagram above, `p` is a pointer to the `'j'` in `"ijk"`.  That means that `p[1]` is the `'k'` in `"ijk"` and `&p[1]` is a pointer to that `'k'`.  Since the `"%s"` format specifier tells `printf` to treat the pointer as a pointer to the first element of a nul-terminated string, it will print the `'k'` pointed to and any subsequent characters until it encounters a `'\0'` character.  That happens to be the next character, so all it prints is "k".
- `&p[5]`: As above, since `p` points to the `'j'` the second array in `a`, `p[5]` is the character 5 positions after that (the `'e'` in `"defg"`).  Again, since the `"%s"` format specifier tells `printf` to print characters starting with the one pointed to by that parameter, it will start at `'e'` and print the `'f'`, and `'g'` before finding a `'\0'` character and stopping.  Thus the output is "efg".

Answer (score 0):

I'll try to explain below how each of these statements end up getting interpreted by the compiler.

---

```
char a[][5] = { "abc", "ijk", "defg", "opq" };
```

To the compiler, this resolves to an array of pointers where each pointer points to an array of characters (AKA string literals).

---

```
char *p = &a[1][1];
```

To start with, `a[1]` resolves to the pointer to the string `"ijk"`. Therefore, `a[1][1]` or `(a[1])[1]` is indexing into the string `"ijk"` to get the character `'j'`. The code then stores the address of this 'j' character into `char* p` by using the `&` operator to get its address in memory.

---

```
printf("%d,%s,%s", a[2] - a[0], &p[1], &p[5]);
```

Let's go arg-by-arg:

```
printf("%d", a[2] - a[0]);
```

As mentioned before, a is an array of character pointers. Therefore, `a[2]` returns a pointer and `a[0]` returns a pointer. As pointers are fundamentally just integers representing addresses, subtracting two pointers gives another integer. In this case, you get `10` because that just happens to be the difference of those two addresses.

```
printf("%s", &p[1]);
```

As mentioned before, `p` is equal to the address of the letter 'j' of the string `"ijk"`. Therefore, `p[1]` will resolve to `*(p + 1)` and will now **equal** the letter `'k'`. Then, applying `&` reverts the de-referencing and finally returns the address to the letter `'k'`. Finally, the `%s` format specify will print an entire **null terminated** string. Because all string literals are null terminated and `'k'` was the last letter of the string literal `"ijk"`, the final string printed by `printf` is simply `"k"`.

```
printf("%s", &p[5]);
```

Again, `p` is equal to the address of the letter `'j'` of the string `"ijk"`. Therefore, `p[5]` will resolve to `*(p + 5)`. In this case, it is undefined behavior as we are attempting to de-reference an address that goes beyond the length of the string `"ijk"`. However, the program does not crash because we just so happen to land on the address of the letter `'e'` in the string "defg". Therefore, `%s` resolves to `"efg"`.

Comment: `a` is not an array of pointers, it is an array of *arrays*.

Comment: An array is, fundamentally, just a pointer.

Comment: No, it is not.  An array is implicitly convertible to a pointer to its first element, but it is not itself a pointer.  Saying an array is a pointer is like saying an `int` is a `double` just because you can implicitly convert from one to the other.

Comment: I stand corrected - arrays do have properties that would be lost when converting to a pointer. I guess I should say that all the operators used in the question simply interpret the array as a pointer.

Comment: I think it's an important distinction to make here.  `a[2] - a[0]` and `&p[5]` would both be undefined if `a` were an array of pointers, but are well-defined since `a` is an array of arrays (the latter is only well-defined because we're dealing with `char`s specifically).

Comment: You're wrong in the first four lines.   The definition of `a` does not resolve to an array of pointers.   It resolves to an array of arrays of five `char`.   Going on, you're incorrectly describing `a[1]` as a pointer, whereas it is a (reference to) an array of five `char`.

Comment: I admit I skipped explaining that the elements of arrays are stored contiguously in memory with no padding. Without that, `a[2] - a[0]` and `&p[5]` would be undefined as you say.

Comment: It's also certainly important to consider the size of the data type of arrays and pointers when indexing into them. For example, given `char a[5] = {...}` and `int32_t b[5] = {...}`, then the operations `a[1]` and `b[1]` would be equivalent to `*(a + 1)` and `*(b + 4)` where the +1 and +4 come from the size of the data type.

Comment: *"where each pointer points to an array of characters (AKA string literals)."* -- No, this cannot be the case. A string literal is an array of `const char`, yet the elements of the elements of `a` are `char` (not `const`). The compiler will not drop `const`-qualification like that.

Comment: @G.Larkham *"given [...] `int32_t b[5] = {...}`, then the operations [...] `b[1]` would be equivalent to [...] `*(b + 4)` where the +1 and +4 come from the size of the data type."* -- No, `b[1]` is equivalent to `*(b+1)`. The address is increased by `4` because the size of the data type is baked into pointer arithmetic. Hmm... to say that the address is increased by 4, you could state that `b[1]` is equivalent to `static_cast<int32_t*>(static_cast<char*>(b) + 4)` -- the cast to `char*` gives the arithmetic I think you had in mind.